# Blurry sprites in OpenGL (2D) on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a little OpenGL 2D game up and running smoothly at 60 fps (movement is smooth).

But when the sprites are moved fast, there is kind of a ghost sprite or trail after it. A little hard to describe, but sprites starts to look blurry. When the movement is slow, sprites look sharp and clear.

This is not the problem with edges being drawn incorrectly for OpenGL 2D sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the same code drives your slow moving and fast moving sprites, it is probable that what you're seeing is *ghosting* caused by your LCD monitor.

I could not find any proper article for an explanation, but you can find an example image [here](http://hardforum.com/showpost.php?p=1031001362&postcount=504).

Comment: I guess this sounds right. On my Asus TF101 it is more like a tail that fades out (like on the picture on your link), but on my Xperia Arc it is more like the sprites are followed by a single "ghost sprite".

Anybody knows about a device or screen type where this is not happening.